# React image not loading on a specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have gave my `img` element `src={obj.url}` and it works just as it is supposed to when I go to see the dev tools of the browser. The image has the assigned url address as a picture source but that picture is not being displayed on the screen as if it was a broken link. Also, the same link works on the parent component and the picture renders with no problems. I'll include screenshots and codes of my two component.
**Parent component:**
[image]

When pressed "Add to cart", the current item is being added to a cart and it will be shown in a list on a checkout page which is a child component.

**Checkout page**
[image]

Here is a Parent component's code:

```
function Checkout() {
  let [, , , , item, setItem] = useContext(DataContext);
  console.log(item);
  let itemList = item.map((obj) => {
    return <CheckoutItems img={obj.url} title={obj.name} price={obj.price} />;
  });
  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <h1>Your items</h1>
      <div className="checkoutItems">{itemList}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Checkout component code:**

```
function CheckoutItems({ img, title, price }) {
  return (
    <div className="checkItem">
      <div>
        <img scr={img} />
        <h2>{title}</h2>
      </div>
      <h2>{price}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you spelled `scr` instead of `src`. Is it while copy/pasting or in the original code?

Comment: Nope, that was the mistake that caused my error, thank you, you can write that as an answer so I can check it as a solution. Thanks again, this happens to me a lot :'D

Comment: Doesn't matter this will be closed due to just being a typo error :D happy coding